# How to get value success and value true recaptcha and place to if condition?

Tags: php, recaptcha

this is the code,

```
$response=@file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

and this the result when I print_r($response);

```
{ "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2016-09-17T03:11:53Z", "hostname": "www.blabla.com" }
```

actually I want to make codition with if condition.
for example :

```
if ($response success == true)
```

how do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Response you are getting is in JSON format so for that you have to decode to php array and after that you can use it, see below:

```
$response=@file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$data = json_decode($response, true);
if($data['success'] == true) {
    // Here your code
}
```

Comment: Accept the answer if you are satisfied

Comment: how to accept the answer, I cant voted, my reputation less than 15.

Comment: When you hover on Answer, you will see Green Right sybmol, click on it

Comment: oh symbol check list right ? ok I see.. thanks Shri Suresh.